# How can I use Numerical-Methods to solve that equation ...

Tags: numerical-methods

Use the Newton-Raphson iteration method (NR) to find one positive root ( Xr > 0 ) of the equation $ X^3 +X -1 =0 $ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set $f(x)=x^3+x-1$ and iterate with the Newton Raphson formula:

$$ x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}. $$ You need to guess a value for $x_0$ to start the iteration. Also, $f'(x_n)$ is the derivative of your function $f$ evaluated at $x_n$. If your iterations don't converge, try a different starting value $x_0$.

Hope this helps some.

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Answer (score 3):

**Approach outline:**

A plot (courtesy of [*Wolfram-Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+%2B+x+-+1+%3D+0%2C+%28x%2C-5%2C5%29)) of the function shows:

[image]

Choose a starting point, say:

$$x_0 = 1$$

Write the Newton Iteration formula as:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x_n - \dfrac{x_n^3 + x_n -1}{3 x_n^2 + 1}$$

Write out the iterates $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$ and find:

$$x_5 = 0.682328$$

Comment: Thanks for the right answer , i wish i had 15 reputation to give you vote up :(

Comment: Thank you so much , any way i am student faculty of mechanical engineering , thank you again 7 you are welcome too :D